# Setting up a mixed model or a split-plot ANOVA for an experiment with male/female fishes in replicated tanks

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data, split-plot

I am designing an experiment with juvenile fishes. There are 12 replicated tanks. In each of the first 6 tanks there is a even mix of male and female fish (100 of each sex in each tank); 3 of these tanks will be treated with chemical A, and 3 treated with chemical B. The remaining 6 tanks will be set up identically but using a different genetic family of fish. The measured response is male and female survival in each tank/treatment.

When constructing a mixed model, I am assuming that this is a simple nested design. Would it be correct to include treatment as a model factor, along with tank, fish sex nested in tank, and genetic ID nested within fish sex? How best to deal with sex and genetic ID is what I am most uncertain about. Any suggestions for coding this in R?

Comment: What is your main hypothesis? Are you trying to test the interaction between genetic family and treatment options? Also, from your description, it seems like gender is 50/50 split for all 12 tanks. Is this true?

Comment: Hi there - the prediction is that chemical treatment differentially affects survival of male and female fish. But I am also exploring whether different genetic lines respond the same way. I should point out that survival is measured as time alive - a continuous variable, not a binomial dead or alive. And yes, sex is split 50/50 in all 12 tanks. Thanks.

Comment: Also - I will code in R.

Answer (score 3):

#### Structure of data

Your data are nested, and here is how I would code it, given your research question:

*Level 2*: You have 12 different tanks, each of which should have a *unique* ID number coded as `factor` (I will code this as `tankID`). At the *tank* level, you have two independent variables: genetic family (I will code it as `genfam`, which is a dichotomous `factor`) and treatment (I will code it as `treat`, which is a dichotomous `factor`).

*Level 1*: You have $n$ fish, each of which should have a *unique* ID number coded as `factor` (I will code this as `fishID`). You have one independent variable at this level: sex (which I will code as `sex`, a dichotomous `factor`). Your dependent variable is at this level (as is the case with multilevel models generally): survival (which I will code as `survival`, which I assume is either `int`, `num`, or `dbl`).

Your data should look something like:

```
fishID  tankID  genfam  treat  sex  survival
1       1       A       A      M    12
2       2       A       B      F    8
...     ...     ...     ...    ...  ...
```

...and so on.

#### Model code

I will skip the mathematical/Greek notation, unless you are into that. Since you said you are coding in R, I'll go right to how to code it. I would use the `lme4` and `lmerTest` packages to run your model. I will code your data as `data`. The saturated model would be:

```
lmer(survival ~ sex * treat * genfam + (1 + sex | tankID), data=data)
```

What this is saying is that `survival` is predicted by a three-way interaction between your independent variables of interest (R will automatically fill in all main effects and two-way interactions for you). The stuff in parentheses are the random parts of the model. `1` specifies that there is a different intercept for each tank—called a "random intercept." The `sex` here means that the effect of sex is allowed to differ across different tanks as well—called a "random slope." The pipe `|` means that these effects are nested within tank, called `tankID`. I should also note that `genfam` and `treat` are not included here, because they are at *Level 2*, so the effects of `genfam` and `treat` cannot vary by *Level 2* clusters.

`lme4` does not like testing hypotheses with *p*-values and *t*-tests, especially since the degrees of freedom for multilevel models aren't straightforward, so the package `lmerTest` will automatically add degrees of freedom approximations and *p*-values. Another option is running likelihood ratio tests with the `anova` function and using nested models, but with so many predictors in your model, this would likely be too much of a hassle (and I find that the likelihood ratio and `lmerTest` rarely disagree).

Comment: +1. Given that everything is balanced here, one should be able to set up a classical ANOVA, but it's of course much easier with `lmer`.

Comment: Yes, it could be done with ANOVA, but I am partial to a regression approach, especially in R, which does not have the clearest ANOVA functions (and I do not particularly like the `ez` package).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed - I appreciate your input. I will code this and run it. I will let you know how it turns out. Cheers...

Comment: @GTC Great! I'd be glad to look at your R output or if you have any other questions.

Comment: Cheers mate. Will do. GTC